# Determine pointwise and uniform convergence of a given sequence of functions and calculate an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, uniform-convergence

> Let $f_n:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R},f_n(x)=\frac {ne^{-x}+xe^{-n}}{n+x},\space\space\space\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Study the convergence and calculate: $A_n=\int_0^1f_n(x)dx.$

My attempt:

For the pointwise convergence we take the limit to $\infty$ of $f_n$. And we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {ne^{-x}+xe^{-n}}{n+x}=1,\forall\space\space\space x\geq0.$$

For the uniform convergence we have to calculate:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\geq0}\left|\frac {ne^{-x}+xe^{-n}}{n+x} - 1\right|.$$

I took $g:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}, g(x)=\frac {ne^{-x}+xe^{-n}}{n+x} - 1$

But if we take the derivative it gets too complicated, what other ways are there to determine the uniform convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Actually
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ne^{-x}+xe^{-n}}{n+x}=e^{-x}.$$
Hence for the uniform convergence you should consider the limit as $n\to \infty$ of the left-hand side
$$\sup_{x\geq 0}\frac{x|e^{-x}-e^{-n}|}{n+x}\leq 
\sup_{x\geq 0}\frac{xe^{-x}}{n+x}
+\sup_{x\geq 0}\frac{xe^{-n}}{n+x}.$$

Comment: oh right, lol..

Comment: At this point, the numerator isn't maximum when the denominator is minimum, then $x=0$ so the numerator will be $0$ and then $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$?

Comment: Yes, the convergence is uniform, but  I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: I was thinking about the fraction... a fraction is maximum when the denominator is minimum, right? And the denominator is minimum at $x=0$, right?

Comment: See my edited answer. Is it clear now how to show uniform convergence?

Comment: yeah, take $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ the insides of RHS sups and calculate their maximum and take the limit as $n\to\infty$ you get $0$ on RHS, thus LHS goes to $0$ too

Comment: Well done! Now  it should be easy to find the limit of the given integral.

Comment: Indeed it is...

Comment: Are there any sup properties that I should know?

Comment: $\sup_{x\in I}(g(x)+h(x))\le\sup_{x\in I}(g(x)) + \sup_{x\in I}(h(x))$

Comment: Yeah but something besides that

Comment: Sorry, I have no special property to mention.

Answer (score 0):

First verify that the $\forall n\in\Bbb N\ \sup\limits_{x\ge0} \frac{ne^{-x}+xe^{-n}}{n+x}$ is attained when $x$ goes to zero from the right.

And then compute that $\sup$

> It's 1

Comment: Can you do such thing that $\sup A(x) + \sup B(x) = \sup (A(x) + B(x))$?

Comment: No but $\sup(A+B)\le\sup(A) + \sup(B)$